# Encontrar si TODOS i^2 (i al cuadrado) son divisores

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tengo que averiguar si un número es poderoso, es decir, si todos sus factores primos al cuadrado son divisores también.

Por ejemplo, 36 es poderoso, ya que los únicos primos que son divisores suyos son 2 y 3, y también se cumple que 4 y 9 son divisores de 36.

Yo escribí el siguiente código, pero tengo el siguiente problema: si SOLO UN i^2 es divisor, me devuelve `True`; yo necesito saber si TODOS los i^2 son divisores de ese número y que recién ahí me retorne `True` o `False`.

Escribí este código en la función.

```
def poderoso(n):
    for i in range(1,n):
        if n%i==0 and primo(i) and n%i**2==0:
            return True
    return False
```

¿Me podrian ayudar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haciendole algunos cambios a tu codigo

```py
def poderoso(n):
     is_poderoso = True # De principio defines que todos los primos son poderosos
     for i in range(1,n):
         if primo(i) and n%i==0: #Solo compruebas los numeros primos divisores
             if n%i**2!=0: # 
                 is_poderoso = False
     return is_poderoso
```

**Explicación:**
Tu codigo retornaba `True` en cuanto encontrara un numero primo que elevado al cuadrado fuera divisor. Lo que hice fue justamente lo contrario, buscar un numero primo que fuera divisor pero su cuadrado no y retornar ese resultado.

Comment: Mejoraría mucho la calidad de la respuesta si explicas por qué has cambiado el código o cuál es el fallo lógico que has arreglado con dicho cambio. Mira [answer]. Un saludo.

Comment: Muchas gracias!

Comment: Esta función devolverá verdadero para un número que no tenga divisores primos. No sé si ese número es poderoso o no, pero lo menciono porque creo que no se ha tomado en cuenta o no se ha aclarado ese punto. El ejemplo explicado en la pregunta, no menciona el uno ni que hacer si no hay divisores primos. Además, el uno en realidad no es primo.

Comment: @jachguate cierto, imagino que te refieras a los numeros primos en si